# How download and install a setup file automatically via python

Tags: python, installation

I wrote a program in `python 3.6.2` .

I converted `.py` to a **setup file**.

I want in python program or want to write a function which downloads the newer version of program and installs it automatically and removes Old version.
I searched it in internet but not found a good solution.
Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Setuptools?
From their website:
"Automatically find/download/install/upgrade dependencies at build time using the EasyInstall tool, which supports downloading via HTTP, FTP, Subversion, and SourceForge, and automatically scans web pages linked from PyPI to find download links. (It’s the closest thing to CPAN currently available for Python.)"

http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html